# Chaining container error in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to kubernetes and docker. I am trying to chain 2 containers in a pod such that the second container should not be up until the first one is running. I searched and got a solution [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/1996). It says to add "depends" field in YAML file for the container which is dependent on another container. Following is a sample of my YAML file:

```
apiVersion: v1beta4
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test
  labels:
    apps: test
spec:
      containers:
      - name: container1
        image: <image-name>
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8080
            hostPort: 8080
      - name: container2
        image: <image-name>
        depends: ["container1"]
```

Kubernetes gives me following error after running the above yaml file:

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "new.yaml": Pod in version "v1beta4" cannot be handled as a Pod: no kind "Pod" is registered for version "v1beta4"
```

Is the `apiVersion` problem here? I even tried `v1`, `apps/v1`, `extensions/v1` but got following errors (respectively):

```
error: error validating "new.yaml": error validating data: ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[1]): unknown field "depends" in io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

error: unable to recognize "new.yaml": no matches for apps/, Kind=Pod

error: unable to recognize "new.yaml": no matches for extensions/, Kind=Pod
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you have access to edit your docker image?

Comment: @aerokite Yes, I have

Comment: you can do this, if you modify your 1st container image

Answer (score 0):

As I understand there is no field called **depends** in the Pod Specification.

You can verify and validate by following command:

```
kubectl explain pod.spec --recursive
```

I have attached a link to understand the structure of the k8s resources.
[kubectl-explain](https://blog.heptio.com/kubectl-explain-heptioprotip-ee883992a243)

Answer (score 0):

There is no property "depends" in the `Container` API object.

You split your containers in two different pods and let the kubernetes cli wait for the first container to become available:

```
kubectl create -f container1.yaml --wait # run command until the pod is available. 
kubectl create -f container2.yaml --wait
```

Comment: what is your `kubectl` version?